# android drawable identifier in a database

Tags: android, database, drawable

what is the best way to store a drawable identifier in a database? by is id? but if it is generated it can change, what to do? I've been looking arround but can't find complete information about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why would you want to store drawable in database , you can simply create a Integer[] array containing all the ids from R.java class

like

```
Integer[] myDrawables = new Integer[]{
R.drawable.xdrawable,
R.drawable.ydrawable,
R.drawable.zdrawable,
}
```

now to access them becomes much easier. I usually define them in public static scope to make them accessible from anywhere

Comment: my ideia was to have a dynamic so the user could insert more, but that's a good ideia, I think I can work with it. thank you very much!

Comment: resources which are accessed via `R.` cannot be dynamic. a user cannot modify them(add, delete, etc)